# Image above another section after using position absolute

Tags: css, flexbox

i'am working on react app , i have a container that have two items inside it , i have to make one above the other , so i made the container relative and the two items absolute , i got what i want , but the section bellow the container become beyond the first container , and i don't want this , the cards should be bellow the container
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use grid instead absolute positionning. You can set more than 1 element inside the same cell.

display:grid creates a container of a single column and a single row. It will create a new row for each children, unless you give the children the same cell(row/col) to stand in.

example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
  min-height: 200px;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
  margin: auto;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
}
section > img,
section > div {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  max-width: 250px;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
}
img {
  margin: auto auto 0 0;
}
div {
  margin: 0 0 auto auto;
  background: hotpink;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
  padding: 0 30px;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
  width: 180px;/*demo purpose , use your own value or not at all */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>Lorem blabla</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/250/166">
</section>
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/100/166">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/100/166">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/100/166">
  </figure>
</section>
```